# Containerd can`t find the image in the private registry, so k8s can't get the image for the container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containerd, nexus

I try configure k8s cluster. I have private docker registry on the nexus server and try pull image from it. When i use docker pull all work correctly, but when i use helm for deploy my app, i have error: `Failed to pull image "x.x.x.x:8124/test_build:1.0.0": rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image "x.x.x.x:8124/test_build:1.0.0": failed to resolve reference "x.x.x.x:8124/test_build:1.0.0": x.x.x.x:8124/test_build:1.0.0: not found` , [but this image is in the registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnzU4.png).

this my configuration files

/etc/containerd/config.toml

```
disabled_plugins = []
imports = ["/etc/containerd/config.toml"]
oom_score = 0
plugin_dir = ""
required_plugins = []
root = "/var/lib/containerd"
state = "/run/containerd"
temp = ""
version = 2

[cgroup]
  path = ""

[debug]
  address = ""
  format = ""
  gid = 0
  level = ""
  uid = 0

[grpc]
  address = "/run/containerd/containerd.sock"
  gid = 0
  max_recv_message_size = 16777216
  max_send_message_size = 16777216
  tcp_address = ""
  tcp_tls_ca = ""
  tcp_tls_cert = ""
  tcp_tls_key = ""
  uid = 0

[metrics]
  address = ""
  grpc_histogram = false

[plugins]

  [plugins."io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler"]
    deletion_threshold = 0
    mutation_threshold = 100
    pause_threshold = 0.02
    schedule_delay = "0s"
    startup_delay = "100ms"

  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri"]
    device_ownership_from_security_context = false
    disable_apparmor = false
    disable_cgroup = false
    disable_hugetlb_controller = true
    disable_proc_mount = false
    disable_tcp_service = true
    enable_selinux = false
    enable_tls_streaming = false
    enable_unprivileged_icmp = false
    enable_unprivileged_ports = false
    ignore_image_defined_volumes = false
    max_concurrent_downloads = 3
    max_container_log_line_size = 16384
    netns_mounts_under_state_dir = false
    restrict_oom_score_adj = false
    sandbox_image = "k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6"
    selinux_category_range = 1024
    stats_collect_period = 10
    stream_idle_timeout = "4h0m0s"
    stream_server_address = "127.0.0.1"
    stream_server_port = "0"
    systemd_cgroup = false
    tolerate_missing_hugetlb_controller = true
    unset_seccomp_profile = ""

    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".cni]
      bin_dir = "/opt/cni/bin"
      conf_dir = "/etc/cni/net.d"
      conf_template = ""
      ip_pref = ""
      max_conf_num = 1

    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd]
      default_runtime_name = "runc"
      disable_snapshot_annotations = true
      discard_unpacked_layers = false
      ignore_rdt_not_enabled_errors = false
      no_pivot = false
      snapshotter = "overlayfs"

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.default_runtime]
        base_runtime_spec = ""
        cni_conf_dir = ""
        cni_max_conf_num = 0
        container_annotations = []
        pod_annotations = []
        privileged_without_host_devices = false
        runtime_engine = ""
        runtime_path = ""
        runtime_root = ""
        runtime_type = ""

        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.default_runtime.options]

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes]

        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc]
          base_runtime_spec = ""
          cni_conf_dir = ""
          cni_max_conf_num = 0
          container_annotations = []
          pod_annotations = []
          privileged_without_host_devices = false
          runtime_engine = ""
          runtime_path = ""
          runtime_root = ""
          runtime_type = "io.containerd.runc.v2"

          [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc.options]
            BinaryName = ""
            CriuImagePath = ""
            CriuPath = ""
            CriuWorkPath = ""
            IoGid = 0
            IoUid = 0
            NoNewKeyring = false
            NoPivotRoot = false
            Root = ""
            ShimCgroup = ""
            SystemdCgroup = false

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.untrusted_workload_runtime]
        base_runtime_spec = ""
        cni_conf_dir = ""
        cni_max_conf_num = 0
        container_annotations = []
        pod_annotations = []
        privileged_without_host_devices = false
        runtime_engine = ""
        runtime_path = ""
        runtime_root = ""
        runtime_type = ""

        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.untrusted_workload_runtime.options]

    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".image_decryption]
      key_model = "node"

    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
      config_path = ""

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.auths]



      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs]

        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."x.x.x.x:8124"]

           [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."x.x.x.x:8124".tls] 
              ca_file = "" 
              cert_file = "" 
              insecure_skip_verify = true 
              key_file = "" 

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.headers]

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]

        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."x.x.x.x:8124"]
          endpoint = ["http://x.x.x.x:8124"]

    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".x509_key_pair_streaming]
      tls_cert_file = ""
      tls_key_file = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.internal.v1.opt"]
    path = "/opt/containerd"

  [plugins."io.containerd.internal.v1.restart"]
    interval = "10s"

  [plugins."io.containerd.internal.v1.tracing"]
    sampling_ratio = 1.0
    service_name = "containerd"

  [plugins."io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt"]
    content_sharing_policy = "shared"

  [plugins."io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups"]
    no_prometheus = false
  [plugins."io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux"]
    no_shim = false
    runtime = "runc"
    runtime_root = ""
    shim = "containerd-shim"
    shim_debug = false

  [plugins."io.containerd.runtime.v2.task"]
    platforms = ["linux/amd64"]
    sched_core = false

  [plugins."io.containerd.service.v1.diff-service"]
    default = ["walking"]

  [plugins."io.containerd.service.v1.tasks-service"]
    rdt_config_file = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs"]
    root_path = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs"]
    root_path = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devmapper"]
    async_remove = false
    base_image_size = ""
    discard_blocks = false
    fs_options = ""
    fs_type = ""
    pool_name = ""
    root_path = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.native"]
    root_path = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs"]
    root_path = ""
    upperdir_label = false

  [plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs"]
    root_path = ""

  [plugins."io.containerd.tracing.processor.v1.otlp"]
    endpoint = ""
    insecure = false
    protocol = ""

[proxy_plugins]

[stream_processors]

  [stream_processors."io.containerd.ocicrypt.decoder.v1.tar"]
    accepts = ["application/vnd.oci.image.layer.v1.tar+encrypted"]
    args = ["--decryption-keys-path", "/etc/containerd/ocicrypt/keys"]
    env = ["OCICRYPT_KEYPROVIDER_CONFIG=/etc/containerd/ocicrypt/ocicrypt_keyprovider.conf"]
    path = "ctd-decoder"
    returns = "application/vnd.oci.image.layer.v1.tar"

  [stream_processors."io.containerd.ocicrypt.decoder.v1.tar.gzip"]
    accepts = ["application/vnd.oci.image.layer.v1.tar+gzip+encrypted"]
    args = ["--decryption-keys-path", "/etc/containerd/ocicrypt/keys"]
    env = ["OCICRYPT_KEYPROVIDER_CONFIG=/etc/containerd/ocicrypt/ocicrypt_keyprovider.conf"]
    path = "ctd-decoder"
    returns = "application/vnd.oci.image.layer.v1.tar+gzip"

[timeouts]
  "io.containerd.timeout.bolt.open" = "0s"
  "io.containerd.timeout.shim.cleanup" = "5s"
  "io.containerd.timeout.shim.load" = "5s"
  "io.containerd.timeout.shim.shutdown" = "3s"
  "io.containerd.timeout.task.state" = "2s"

[ttrpc]
  address = ""
  gid = 0
  uid = 0
```

/etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{ "insecure-registries":["x.x.x.x:8124"] }
```

Also i have k8s secret for prtivate registry, ofc i use this secret in my deployment.yaml

```
Name:         regcred
Namespace:    test
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson

Data
====
.dockerconfigjson:  118 bytes
```

Nexus version 3.14.0-04